# Does JVM throw exception to OS

Tags: java, exception

I was asked this question that does JVM throw Exception to OS if main throws? JVM stops application execution but where this exception will be handled?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    display();
}

public static void display() throws Exception {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

If this can occur with any exception, please specify.

Comment: Incomprehensible. What on earth does 'does JVM throw Exception if main throws' actually mean? It's either a tautology or nonsense.

Comment: updated. And "main" is just an example, in case of web server, it can occur.

Comment: @EJP I thought it pretty clearly meant that the JVM would throw an exception back to the operating system, based on the title. The English isn't perfect but I had no problems understanding the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not handled by the OS, but by the JVM itself. From the [Java language specification §11.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3):

> If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found, then the current thread (the thread that encountered the exception) is terminated

Your JVM will be running with a single thread, which will be terminated. The JVM will then shut itself down, according to [JLS §12.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.8) (emphasis added):

> A program terminates all its activity and exits when one of two things happens:
>
> - **All the threads that are not daemon threads terminate.**
> - Some thread invokes the exit method of class Runtime or class System, and the exit operation is not forbidden by the security manager.

This can occur with any type of exception at all. Note that in terms of the language specification, [an "exception" is actually a `java.lang.Throwable` and any of its subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1). This means that `Error`s also terminate threads/JVMs, and anything else inheriting from `Throwable`, rather than just objects extending `Exception`.

Comment: so there is no way that JVM will throw exception to OS? not even in case of OutOfMemory while excepting?

Comment: I'm not sure there's even an OS that includes a concept of an application throwing an exception back to the OS. Exceptions are inherently application-scoped: the OS can't do anything useful with any application exception ever, except maybe for logging it. But in this particular case, no, the OS will definitely never receive an "exception" (whatever that would happen to mean for that particular OS). The JVM will simply shut down.

Comment: I believe so. But you see some times you see server logging dumps, in that case, JVM does throw exception and OS only logs at random location or some temp location. No?

Comment: That's a good point - there are [faults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (e.g. segfault) which the OS can respond to (which again usually seems to be for logging). In the case of the JVM, though, I believe core dumps are actually done by the JVM itself, hence why they can be enabled by a JVM switch.

Comment: I believed the same. But the location I always found random. Many times in home directory with folder name **~/temp**

Answer (score 0):

Java runs in JVM, so all exceptions will be handled in JVM. Simply for your answer, Java exceptions will not throw to OS level. In the other words, you cannot catch JAVA exceptions in OS level.

Hope this answers your question.